# Copy selected text from the Website Java

Tags: java, web, copy

I want to copy the text that's in Red from the following website. I don't want any HTML Code as I could get that but I am looking for a way to simply copy all the text that's in Red. I know I could do that manually but that's not something that I am looking for. I would really appreciate for sharing any code.

```
http://www.srigranth.org/servlet/gurbani.gurbani?Action=Page&Param=1&g=1&h=0&r=0&t=0&p=0&k=0&fb=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) allows you to read a web page and iterate over its content elements.

```
Sting yourURL = "servlet/gurbani.gurbani?Action=Page&Param=1&g=1&h=0&r=0&t=0&p=0&k=0&fb=0";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(yourURL).get();
```

I don't understand what's on that page, but it looks like the text you're after might be the inner html of `a` links with class `dict`.  If that's the case,

```
Elements links = doc.select("a.dict");
```

will give you an iterable collection of `Element` of which you can easily extract the text content:

```
for (Element word : links) {
    String theTextyoureafter = word.html();
}
```

That's the basic idea, you'll probably need to experiment a bit to get it "just right", but there are also a lot of examples on the Jsoup website.

Comment: This is great but I get the text separated by each "word" so I really don't know where the new line started and where it ended. Since you don't understand the text use this one: http://www.srigranth.org/servlet/gurbani.gurbani?Action=Page&Param=1&g=0&h=0&r=0&t=1&p=0&k=0&fb=0

Comment: Anything that's in blue is what I am after. I basically want to add all those lines to my ArrayList. But still thanks a lot for something better than copying manually.

Comment: For the english version the document structure is different (no `a`  element per word), but the idea remains the same.  Try using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to understand the page's structure, but it looks like first finding all `div` elements and the finding all `a` elements in each div could help as as far as I can see each sentence is wrapped into a div.  Do read the [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) manual page, the selectors are quite powerful!  Good luck with your project.